# Multi-part pattern in Merge clause of Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given the following graph:

```
(a)<--(b)-->(c)<--(d)-->(e)<--(f)-->(a)
```

I believe it is (currently) impossible to create a node (g) using the merge clause such that:

```
(g)-->(a)
(g)-->(c)
(g)-->(e)
```

The reason being that it requires a comma to describe the above pattern, and the MERGE clause will not accept a comma. e.g. `(a)<--(g)-->(c), (g)-->(e)`

For ease of reference, see picture below. Given that graph (except node 6), I cannot create node 6 using the MERGE command.

[image: picture of graph]

Can someone come up with a way to do this? I believe new functionality needs to be added, but I'd like to be more reasonably sure there's not a viable workaround before heading down that path.

Comment: What labels are you working with here? Is `g` supposed to have a different label than all other elements in the subgraph? Usually those kind of restrictions can greatly help out.

Comment: In my data, a, c, and e are all of the same type, and b, d, f, and g are all of the same type.
If you're looking at the picture, that means 0, 2, and 4 are one type of node, and all the rest are a second type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this in Cypher, or in APOC right now. That said, there is a workaround. It's a bit manual, you'll need to acquire locks on the nodes in question (we'll use APOC for that), and we'll use `OPTIONAL MATCH` along with `WHERE ... IS NULL` to determine whether or not the center node exists, then create it only when it doesn't.

For this, I'm using the following example graph to mimic yours, before the addition of node 6:

```
create (zero:Node{name:0})
create (one:Node{name:1})
create (two:Node{name:2})
create (three:Node{name:3})
create (four:Node{name:4})
create (five:Node{name:5})

create (zero)<-[:TYPE]-(one)-[:TYPE]->(two)
create (two)<-[:TYPE]-(three)-[:TYPE]->(four)
create (four)<-[:TYPE]-(five)-[:TYPE]->(zero)
```

And now, the query to merge

```
match (node:Node)
where node.name in [0,2,4]

with collect(node) as nodes
call apoc.lock.nodes(nodes)
with nodes[0] as first, nodes[1] as second, nodes[2] as third

optional match (first)<-[:TYPE]-(center)-[:TYPE]->(second)
where (center)-[:TYPE]->(third)
with first, second, third, center
where center is null
// above 'where' will result in no rows if center exists, preventing creation of duplicate pattern below
create (first)<-[:TYPE]-(newCenter:Node{name:6})-[:TYPE]->(second)
create (newCenter)-[:TYPE]->(third)
```